# why the JAXRSIntegration can't lookup JNDI

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, weblogic12c, java-ee-7

i need some help here!

I'm using javaEE 7,  javax-ws-rs 2.0.1 and Weblogic 12.2.1.4.0.

Im getting following error on my Manage Server log:

```
<04.01.2022 16:51 Uhr MEZ> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192505> <An instance of EJB class com.my.company.rest.MyExchangeServer could not be looked up using a simple form name. 
Attempting to look up using the fully-qualified form name.
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up /app/my-company-web-1.7.0.2/MyExchangeServer in /app/webapp/my-company-web/1607311341.; remaining name '/app/my-company-web-1/7/0/2/MyExchangeServer'
```

this happend after the Migration from Weblogic 12.1 to Weblogic 12.2.
The Application runs without problem tough.
Only the ms_logs bothering us, because it take so much memory.

```
@ApplicationPath("rest") 
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> restClasses = new HashSet<>();
        restClasses.add(MyExchangeServer.class);
        return restClasses;
    }
}
```

```
</web-app>
    ...
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey-Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.my.company.rest.ApplicationConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilter</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sun.jersey.server.linking.LinkFiler</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey-Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@Path("serviceInterface")
public class MyExchangeServer {
    ...
}
```

Under JNDI tree i find:
`java:global.my-int-ear.my-company-web.MyExchangeServer!com.my.company.rest.MyExchangeServer`

It seems that the MyExchangeServer class are instantiated by jersey and not from EJB.
Why would JAXRSIntegration trying to look up under /app/my-company-web-1.7.0.2/MyExchangeServer ?

The Application works prefectly tough

Answer (score 0):

now i have found the solution. The porblem was i'm still using JAX-RS 1.0 on my project. Since on WLS 12.2.* JAX-RS 1.0 deprecated. I have to use the JAX-RS 2.*.

So far i only need to change the Jersey configuration on my web.xml. And i'm good to go.

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey-Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <!-- Register resources and providers under my.package. -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>my.company.rest.ApplicationConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <!-- Enable Tracing support. -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.tracing</param-name>
            <param-value>ALL</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey-Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```